# Disable "com.package.name has stopped" pop-up notification

Tags: notifications, user-interface

I am typing, and then, a pop-up flies into the screen, telling me that a random application in the background has halted.

Starting with Android Lollipop, the "OK" button of the pop-up is terribly small, and is **greyed out for one second.** Tapping on the background behind the pop-up does not work.

Apparently, Android is unable to send a notification instead of pop-up on app crashes, so it decides to block the screen like the infamous iOS volume indicator.

#### How do I disable the app crash pop-up?

I am tired of waiting one second and pressing "OK" each time.

Comment: Try using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Create a macro Trigger: Notification Received> select app > any> contains text > add the text you see in notification ; Action: Clear notification> containing text (repeat text)